# How should I distribute a classifier to customers?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, python, consulting

When consulting, I often do my exploratory analysis and prototyping in R, and deliver results on the initial dataset to the client. The client wants to use the trained classifier in a production setting. For example, assume that the client wants to run 1000 records per day through the classifier. **How should I deliver the trained classifier?**

For example:

1. Send paper describing the results and R code that will exactly replicate my work and hope that the client will be able to make a production server and implement it properly?
2. Abandon R after the proof of concept, and write up the classifier in a different programming language (e.g. python) that is more readily deployable by the client?
3. Try to set up a webserver that will run an instance of R?
4. Accept data from the client and run it upon request?

Comment: Try R-Shiny? http://rstudio.github.com/shiny/tutorial/

Comment: Is real time response needed or can all 1000 records be batched together?

Comment: Would it be possible to deliver a PMML format ?

Comment: R-Shiny is a good suggestion -- I browsed through their page earlier today and will probably sign up for the beta test (otherwise, it looks like it falls into the "run your own webserver" approach, though with a better interface than most)

Comment: In my case a real-time response is desirable but it's not strictly necessary. I'm definitely not above accepting data over email and running it myself, but somehow that doesn't seem like the "right" answer.

Comment: Why not ask the client which one of {1,2,3,4}, or perhaps another option, they prefer?